# Javascript - Spliting Sentence into multiple words to Json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search, elasticsearch

I am trying to search something which splits the sentence into words or smaller sentence. I don't know how it is to be understood exactly but i can give you example.

Suppose i have a sentence `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

I wanted this in json array as 
`["The","The quick","The quick brown","The quick brown fox","The quick brown fox jumps","The quick brown fox jumps over","The quick brown fox jumps over the","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]`

I don't know how it should be explained in technical terms but i hope i have given proper example

Update 1 :

I am sorry for the fiddle just clicked in my mind that i wanted bit different results. Example sentence `It is my dream`

Expected Result `["It", "It is", "It is my", "It is my dream","is", "is my", "is my dream", "my", "my dream"]`

Comment: Array is `[]` brackets, and you can do simple `'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split(' ')`

Comment: but that won't give me result like this i believe it will give me array of individual words

Comment: yes, you'll have to build that array yourself, there's no built in if that's what you're asking. What exactly is causing your problems?

Comment: i do understand that it can be done with loop but repeating words again and again and appending them each time is bit tricky

Comment: @ILadis that doesn't give the expected result

Comment: How does your search query look like?

Comment: search query? i am trying to split sentence into word and words in a best posible manner. I will later bind it to the typeahed

Comment: @NetMaster In regards to your "Update 1", that's a separate question, please ask that one in another post.

Comment: Ok @Dayan Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you try this? I wrote a solution that easier to understand

```
string = "Hello how are you my dear?";
function get(string) {
    var ret = [];
    var data = string.split(" ");
    var s = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
        s += data[i] + " ";
        ret.push(s.replace(data[i] + " ",data[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

-UPDATE

```
string = "Hello how are you my dear?";
function get(string,count =0) {
    var ret = [];
    var data = string.split(" ");
    var s = "";
    for(var i = count;i < data.length;i++) {
        s += data[i] + " ";
        ret.push(s.replace(data[i] + " ",data[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I added count for your the thing you wanted, so you can do:

```
get(string,1);
get(string,2);
get(string,3);
get(string,4);
```

Expected output:

```
["how", "how are", "how are you", "how are you my", "how are you my dear?"]
["are", "are you", "are you my", "are you my dear?"]
["you", "you my", "you my dear?"]
["my", "my dear?"]
```

Answer (score 6):

As @Leguest states, a JSON array starts and ends in `[]` brackets, so it should go this way:

```
["The","The quick","The quick brown","The quick brown fox","The quick brown fox jumps","The quick brown fox jumps over","The quick brown fox jumps over the","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
```

I can think a way of doing this. Simply splitting and looping:

```js
var phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ");
var arr = [];
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    str += phrase[i] + " ";
    arr.push(str.trim());
}
console.log("Array:", arr);
console.log("Array string:", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Note that for readibility shake this is not performant (doing a `trim` on each word added). If you want a performant way you can do it right this (only a small change to detect first word):

```js
var phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ");
var arr = [];
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        str += " ";
    }
    str += phrase[i];
    arr.push(str);
}
console.log("Array:", arr);
console.log("Array string:", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: genius you made it look so simple

Comment: Small change to it. I actually wanted this as output `["It", ""It is", "It is my", "It is my dream","is", "is my", "is my dream", "my", "my dream"]` of sentence `It is my dream`

Comment: no I am sorry but it clicked just in my mind so asked

Answer (score 4):

If you want an answer that doesn't involve iterations, this may be what you need:

```js
function getresult(total, current) {
     total.length != 0 ? total.push(total[total.length-1].split(" ").concat([current]).join(" ")) : total.push(current);
     return total;
}
var data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var dataArr = data.split(" ");
var results = dataArr.reduce(getresult, []);
            
console.log(results);
```

The reduce method applies a function(in this case getresult) over the elements of an array(dataArr).
The function needed will operate over an accumulator parameter(that will be the result of the last iteration) and the next element. 
For the first iteration we need an initial value, and that's the second parameter(the empty array)

In order to add new elements to the array we use concat, which returns a new array and so we maintain the immutability.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit what goes on here, specifically `reduce` and the `getresult` function.

Comment: @Yaskier can you please help me with updated question?